# Moving object Left To Right

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my game I am going to add obstaceles that move left to right across the `<div id="outline"></div>`

I've used `setInterval(){...}`  with the `.animate()` In it, and it seems to work only issue is after a little bit of time it leaves the ouline, Below is some code and a link.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
setInterval(function(){
      $("#CObject").animate({
    'marginLeft' : "+=220px" //moves left
    }, 900);
 }, 900);
setInterval(function(){
      $("#CObject").animate({
    'marginLeft' : "-=220px" //moves left
    }, 900);
 }, 1000);
});
```

[***Link.***](http://jsfiddle.net/mrj2q3p0/)

Answer (score 4):

change to this on your "-=220px":

```
setInterval(function(){
    $("#CObject").animate({
      'marginLeft' : "-=220px" //moves left
    }, 900);
}, 900);
```

to match **900** time interval, it's offset by **100**.

Comment: OP's code is on **1000** which offset **100** with "+=220px", so given it time it's offset from the div

Comment: @TimothyGroote The `setInterval` time is changed from 1000 to 900. This fixes the issue.

Comment: @TimothyGroote, yes it's tricky I just spot it in a quick glance and think it's the issue

Comment: Yup, this does look stable.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know. There's another way do what you want without use setInterval, in this case you have to wait the animation ends in order to start the reverse animation.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    animate(false);
});

function animate(reverse) {
    $("#CObject").animate({
        'marginLeft' : (reverse) ? "-=220px" : "+=220px" //moves left
     }, 900, function() {
       // Run when animation finishes
       animate(!reverse); 
    });
}
```

This way you can be sure that animation will finish before start anything else

Comment: Much cleaner way to do this animation. +1

Answer (score 0):

Without setInterval:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function loop() {

        $("#CObject").animate({
            'marginLeft' : "+=220px" //moves left
        }, 900, 'linear', function() {
            loop();
        });

        $("#CObject").animate({
            'marginLeft' : "-=220px" //moves left
        }, 900, 'linear', function() {
            loop();
        });

    }

    loop();

});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q40rhyku/)

create a loop function with the animation and then just call it when the animation finishes.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that the animation is complete, I would just have each direction animation call the other one when it completes. If you look at the API for `animate`, you'll see the fourth parameter is for a function that will be called when the animation is finished. http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    animateRight();
});

function animateRight() {
    $("#CObject").animate({
        'marginLeft' : "+=220px" //moves left
    }, 900, 'swing', animateLeft);
}

function animateLeft() {
    $("#CObject").animate({
        'marginLeft' : "-=220px" //moves right
    }, 900, 'swing', animateRight);
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cgdtfxxu/